# Simplify AngularJS scope with a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to simplify a script with a loop, but I can't get it to work.

I want to convert the following working code and make it shorter to show/hide a div.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);              
app.controller('onderdelenCtrl', function($scope) { 

$scope.spec1 = true;  
$scope.spec2 = true;  
$scope.spec3 = true;
```

...

```
$scope.spec9 = true;  
$scope.togglespec1 = function() {              
$scope.spec1=!$scope.spec1; }             
$scope.togglespec2 = function() {              
$scope.spec2=!$scope.spec2; }        
$scope.togglespec3 = function() {              
$scope.spec3=!$scope.spec3; }
```

...

```
$scope.togglespec9 = function() {              
$scope.spec9=!$scope.spec9; }    
});
```

Into something like:

```
var onderdelenlijst = ["processor", "moederbord", "video", "opslag", "geheugen", "behuizing", "voeding", "dvd", "geluid"];

var indexonderdelenlijst = onderdelenlijst.length;

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);             
app.controller('onderdelenCtrl', function($scope) {
i=0;
while (i < indexonderdelenlijst) {
i++;
var spec = $scope.spec + i;
spec = true;  
togglespec = $scope.togglespec + i;
togglespec = function() {              
spec =! spec; }         
}
});
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have tried multiple things, but it keeps failing somehow.

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well and maybe a fiddle demonstration?

Comment: look my answer. I think this answer solved your problem

Comment: Couldn't get it to work yet: here is the complete code, which I copy in the w3schools editor (link in html section) https://jsfiddle.net/6jmLmyek/ this one is the working: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu4cv1yn/

Comment: I fixed it :) https://jsfiddle.net/fhhwLcy9/ I had to change some things in the html aswel. I used all the solutions below combined and it works, so thanks everyone! But Sandeep you indeed had the best solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get continues **$scope** variable then apply this method
use it :

```
$scope['spec'+i];
```

not

```
var spec = $scope.spec + i;
```

**$scope['spec'+i];** use it all place where you get $scope variable continues...

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array for specs and a toggle function with index as argument.

```
var onderdelenlijst = ["processor", "moederbord", "video", "opslag", "geheugen", "behuizing", "voeding", "dvd", "geluid"];
var indexonderdelenlijst = onderdelenlijst.length;

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);             
app.controller('onderdelenCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.spec = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < indexonderdelenlijst; i++) {
    $scope.spec.push(true);        
  }
  $scope.togglespec = function(index) {
    $scope.spec[index] = !$scope.spec[index];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need js code for toggle a div.

Html is adequate.

```
<div ng-show="showdiv1" ng-click="showdiv1=!showdiv1"></div>

<div ng-show="showdiv2" ng-click="showdiv2=!showdiv2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example, maybe something like this?

JS

```
$scope.specs = [0, 1, 2, 3];

$scope.toggle = function (index) {
    $scope.specs[index] = !$scope.specs[index];
}
```

Markup

```
<div ng-repeat="spec in specs">
    <button ng-click="$scope.toggle($index)">Toggle</button>
</div>
```